# Graph visualization failed in TensorFlow2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am fresher to `TensorFlow2` and I write such code to use autograph in Jupyter.
But I get `Graph visualization failed` error, which give a hint let me refer to [tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1961](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1961).

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def strjoin(x,y):
    z =  tf.strings.join([x,y],separator = " ")
    tf.print(z)
    return z

result = strjoin(tf.constant("hello"),tf.constant("world"))

print(result)

import datetime

import os
stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = os.path.join('data', 'autograph', stamp)


writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True) 

result = strjoin("hello","world")

with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(
        name="autograph",
        step=0,
        profiler_outdir=logdir)

%load_ext tensorboard

%tensorboard --logdir ./data/autograph/
```

[image]

Here are the related packages versions:

```
tensorboard                2.1.1
tensorflow-estimator       2.1.0
tensorflow-gpu             2.1.0
```

It seems that TensorFlow doesn't trace any graph, but I did turn the trace on.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems to work fine in colab, so you might be dealing with a bug specific to Jupyter. If you look inside ./data/autograph, does it contain any files? You should see a directory containing some tf.events files, something like `./data/autograph/20200523-111103/events.out.tfevents.1590232263.874c40919b94.120.15.v2`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

I also meet this problem and using the same code.

The problem is cause by incompatible versions between tensorboard and tensorflow you use.
I created a conda virtual environment for tf2.1, then run the code above and the command `tensorboard --logdir ./data/autograph/`, but it seems that the Terminal use default tensorboard in root environment instead of the tf2.1 environment in using.
So I tried the below command in Terminal:

```
conda activate tf2.1
tensorboard --logdir ./data/autograph/
```

After that, the tensorboard can run correctly.